# Обрезание изображения (скриншотов) | Screenshot crop

Tags: android

Здравствуте, я хочу обрезать скриншоты в android программно. То есть я хочу чтобы пользователь не учавствовал в обрезании(без GUI).. Как это можно реализовать, ведь я видел в туториалах(https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/) только обрезание с участием пользователя(с GUI)?

Comment: Приведите какой-нибудь код, что бы мы могли вам помочь

Comment: Готово, я правил вопрос

Comment: android-studio метка и в целом тематически никак не связана с вашим вопросом, просьба использовать данную метку только в вопросах связанных непосредственно с IDE

Comment: Не знаю:( Тематика скриншотов связана с android studio как по мне

Comment: Вообще не связана. Вы можете реализовать функционал просто в блокноте или даже в консольном текстовом редакторе. Из исходников собрать apk тоже можно из консоли. По сути вопроса - картинка это двумерный массив цветов. Обрезать можно программно скопирова оный в двумерный массив меньшего размера

Comment: ЮрийСПб♦️, спасибо

Comment: Ааа, я понял. Это тематика библиотек для android studio. Тогда извиняюсь. Не знал